# Ajax-Enabled WCF Service return error 500 when hosted on IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I'm trying to set up an Ajax-Enabled WCF Service with my Web Application. I can use it just fine with visual studio, however when I publish the website and host it on IIS, the service doesn't seem to be managed properly.

For instance :

When Hosting the web site through Visual Studio (with cassini I assume), I get a Javascript file generated on my localhost `localhost:62006/WebServices/SaphirExternService.svc/jsdebug` which allows me to call the method of the webservice from the javascript.

However on the production environnement, when I should be getting `/WebServices/SaphirExternService.svc/js` there is a server 500 error. Actually I cant even browse to `url/WebServices/SaphirExternService.svc` (same 500).

The error is as follow (translated approximately) :

```
could not load the type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler' from the assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

MyService.svc contains :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" 
Debug="true" Service="WebApplication.WebServices.SaphirExternService" 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"
CodeBehind="SaphirExternService.svc.cs" %>
```

The service is declared as follow in the aspx :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/SaphirExternService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

and called as follow in the javascript :

```
var service = new WebServices.SaphirExternService();
service.DoWork("test", DoWorkSuccess, null, null);
```

Finally the Web.config :

```
<services>
  <service name="WebApplication.WebServices.SaphirExternService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication.WebServices.SaphirExternServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication.WebServices.SaphirExternService" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebApplication.WebServices.SaphirExternServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

This works fine on visual studio itself however this no longer work when published and hosted on IIS (since the `/js` file is not generated, SaphirExternService is not defined). I've tried using several endpoint configuration (like the `bindingConfiguration` attribute) to no avail. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my issue in case someone needs it for future reference. The svc file were not mapped properly in IIS. I removed all `*.svc` related configuration in the Handler Mappings. Then in two steps :

1. Added a new Mime Type :

   - **Extension:** .svc
   - **MIME type:** application/octet-stream
2. In Handler Mapping  > Added a new managed code Handler:

   - **Request path:** *.svc
   - **Type:** System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler
   - **Name:** svc-Integrated